# Is there an F# equivalent to Python's Counter collection?

Tags: python, f#, counter

Looking to port some Python code to F#.  I'm new to both languages.  The Python code uses the "Counter" collection "where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values".  In Python for example:

```
cnt = Counter()

for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
   cnt[word] += 1

cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})

>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>> cnt = Counter()

>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:

>> ... cnt[word] += 1

>> cnt

>> Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Is there an F# equivalent to Python's Counter collection?

Comment: So just a `Dictionary<string,int>`? You don't need such a class in .NET and F# though. If you want to count occurences you can use either LINQ methods or `groupBy` on any collection of words to aggregate data and count occurences. This avoids using mutable structures and results in safer code that's easier to parallelize.

Comment: This datastructure is called a "Multiset" in mathematics and every other programming language. I am not sure why the Python community chose to use a different name. There is no multiset in the .NET Standard libraries, but I am sure there are a dozen or so implementations you can find on the web. In fact, writing your own is a common topic in entry-level tutorials for writing generic collections. There's also the Bag datastructure, which is similar, but its interface is more like "array minus ordering" than "set plus multiplicity".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: AFAIK, `groupBy` + `count` is O(n) in the amortized worst-case, whereas a purpose-built multiset can be O(1) amortized worst-case.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What about *loading* that multiset? In order to get that O(1) you need to pay the O(n) up front. Besides it's trivial to add a `ToDictionary()` at the end to convert the counts to a dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F#, state mutation such as `cnt[word] += 1` is possible, but it is generally avoided.  Instead, computations are expressed by using higher-order functions to describe the intent of an operation, rather than using imperative commands to describe the mechanism.  In this case, a typical F# solution might look something like this:

```
let counts =
    ["red"; "blue"; "red"; "green"; "blue"; "blue"]
    |> List.groupBy id
    |> Map.ofList
    |> Map.map (fun _ words -> words |> List.length)
```

Here, we take the same list of words, then we use `List.groupBy` to to create a list of lists, and we pass it the `id` function to say that we want to group by the values themselves (the words in the list).  The list of words is actually the second parameter to `List.groupBy`, but we use the `|>` ("pipe-forward") operator to pass the preceding value as the last parameter to the next function.  This is useful, because it allows us to chain operations together, as we see with the next line, where we take the list of lists returned by `List.groupBy` and pass it to `Map.ofList`, which gives us a `Map<string, string list>`.

A `Map` type allows us to do lookups by a key, like the `Counter` type.  We then convert the `Map<string, string list>` into a `Map<string, int>` with the counts of each word by piping the result of `Map.ofList` into `Map.map`, which lets us pass a function that converts the values in the map from one type to another.  In this case, we want to convert the values from a `string list` to an `int`, so we take the `string list` (which we'll call 'words') and pass it to `List.length` to get the count.  The function parameter for `Map.map` takes two parameters, the key and the values, but we're only interested in the values, so I've ignored the key parameter by calling it `_`.  This gives us a `Map<string, int>` which contains the word as the key and the count of that word in the list as the value:

```
val counts : Map<string,int> = map [("blue", 3); ("green", 1); ("red", 2)]
```

**EDIT**

As kvb mentioned in the comments, the F# `List` module already has a `countBy` function that combines the `groupBy` with the `List.length` for you.  That makes the code even simpler:

```
let counts =
    ["red"; "blue"; "red"; "green"; "blue"; "blue"]
    |> List.countBy id
    |> Map.ofList
```

This gives the same result as the above, because we take the list of `string * int` tuples and pipe it to `Map.ofList`, so that we get the lookup capabilities of a map (like the Python `Counter` object).

Comment: Although `groupBy` certainly works, using `countBy` instead would simplify things.  All you really need is to pipe the results of `countBy id` into `Map` and you're done.

Comment: @kvb Good point, I forgot about `countBy`.  I've added a second example.