# Is there a .NET object in C# that mimics a Python Counter Class from Collection?

Tags: python, c#, .net, dictionary, counter

I have the docs here for the [Counter Class in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

I have a Hash Set in C# that I generated from a List of string in C#. I have been using this code block to count the items.

```
foreach( var item in dict_of_dates.Values)
{
    foreach(var item2 in item)
    {
        if (item2 == set_1.ElementAt(0))
            count++;
        else if (item2 == set_1.ElementAt(1))
            count_1++;
        else if (item2 == set_1.ElementAt(2))
            count_2++;
        else if (item2 == set_1.ElementAt(3))
            count_3++;
        else if (item2 == set_1.ElementAt(4))
            count_4++;
        else if (!set_1.Contains(item2))
            count_5++;
    }
}
```

The issue with this code is that if I do not know the number of items that are going to be in my set. It would just require a increase in number of if elseif conditions and saving the count to the counter variables. I would like to avoid this seeing that it makes the code bulky in general.  My general question is, is there a prebuilt counter class in C# possibly using lambdas and the hash set or do I have to create my own Counter Class?

I am trying to get a collection that has the following output:

```
{"a": 20, "b": 30, "c": 40}
```

This is so like that I can loop over the output and plot the keys and values.

I have read this question and it is in F#.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166170/is-there-an-f-equivalent-to-pythons-counter-collection)

Solution that worked:

```cs
var h = dict_of_dates.Values
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach(var item in h)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: This can be done with LINQ but can you specify the typing of `dict_of_dates`? Trying to figure out why you are doing two foreach loops

Comment: It's better to explain what you actually want, not ask for "something like that other thing that you probably don't know about". Using `ElementAt` to access items is a very strong smell too. If the collection supports indexing, it should be used. If it doesn't, `ElementAt` is *very* expensive as it has to iterate all items until it reaches that element

Comment: There isn't an object for this, and F# is not using an object for this either. But you *can* build one if you want, technically. Tbh LINQ/F#'s list operations are preferable

Comment: What type is your input? You probably can use `GroupBy` to create a Histogram.

Comment: If you want a dictionary of counters you can use `Dictionary<string,int>` and increment the counters explicitly. `dict["a']=dict["a"]+1;`. You can use `TryGetValue` to handle missing entries

Comment: Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fQ8Kq ?

Comment: Sorry I just got flooded with questions I am going to aim to answer them.

Comment: If you want to count identical items though, you can use LINQ to group the items and count them. Python's Counter class is essentially how you *implement* that grouping. The higher level construct would be `items.GroupBy(it=>it.Name).Select(g=>new {g.Key, Count=g.Count()});`.

Comment: LINQ implements something similar to Python's Counter using the more generic and immutable [Lookup<TKey,TElement>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-7.0) class which contains all the grouped elements by key. A Lookup can't be created directly, it must be created using `ToLookup()`

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I was thinking about this just now.

Comment: The dotnetfiddle worked.

Comment: @Narish That is because it is a List<List<string>>.

Comment: @Wandering two quick things 1) you can either post your solution code as an answer on this thread mark it as the solution, or mark Fildor's answer response as the solution 2) I have edited the code for clarity but specifically removed the intermediate call `.ToList()`. In LINQ everything attempts to fluently return `IEnumerable<T>` which you can think of as an abstraction of any iterable collection, so many times in LINQ intermediate dumps to a List<T> are not necessary. Calling `.ToList()` also forces execution early, so you want to be conscious of when you actually need this

Comment: Related: [C# | Dictionary | How to increase or decrease numeric value of an existing key in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71986658/c-sharp-dictionary-how-to-increase-or-decrease-numeric-value-of-an-existing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using LINQ would be:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c","a", "b", "c","a", "b", "c","a", "b","a", "b","a", "c"};
        var histogram = input.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g=> g.Count());
    }
}
```

This creates a histogram of the elements of the list by grouping them by value and then counting the elements of each group.

In Action : [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fQ8Kq)

Comment: I modified your code to merge it with my input it worked I attached the solution in my question. Thanks for you help. +1